# Discord.js v13 TypeError in slash command handler

Tags: discord.js

I want to create a basic mute command that simply adds a role to the user without a time parameter, how can I implement this in Discord.js v13? I already have slash commands and a handler command setup however I am receiving the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

**My Code:**

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("mute")
    .setDescription("El bot muteara a un usuario del server")
    .addUserOption(option => 
        option
        .setName("miembro") // target
        .setDescription("Mencione al miembro que desea mutear")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption(option => 
        option
        .setName("razon") // reason
        .setDescription("Razon por la que el usuario sera muteado")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),

    async run(client, interaction){
        const target = interaction.options.getUser("miembro");
        const reason = interaction.options.getString("razon");

        if(!interaction.guild.roles.cache.get('902652079762468975')) return interaction.followUp({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription("El rol de muteado no existe")]})
        await target.roles.cache.add("902652079762468975");
        interaction.followUp({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("GREEN").setDescription(`✅ ${target} ha sido muteado. Razon:${reason}`)]})
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? For example, what is `interaction` parameter in the async function called "run"?

Comment: Which cache is the error firing on? DJS13 Changed many things, one of which being the internal cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on the latest version of djs13, You want to use [`option.getMember()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getMember) instead of [`option.getUser`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getUser).

getUser returns the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/User) object which does not have any guild information, including roles. `getMember` returns the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.0/class/GuildMember) object which has reference to the roles cache. This will only work if the command is fired from a guild channel.

If you want your command available outside of the guild, you must use getUser and look the user's id up in the guild's member cache manually.

This may require changes to your command registration to accommodate the change in value type.

> [`Documentation`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getMember)

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code

```js
async run(client, interaction){
    const target = interaction.options.getMember("miembro");
    const reason = interaction.options.getString("razon");
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("GREEN")
    .setDescription(`✅ ${target} has been muted. Reason:${reason}`)

    await target.roles.add('role-id');
    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed]})
}
```